# Django: Right way of using URL patterns: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, django

Im new to Django and im trying to display Hello world from my app.

Im stuck in giving the right URL pattern in urls.py

** **UPDATED: Working** **

My folder structure is as:

**var\www\html\Python_PS\DjangoDemo\boardgames\urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^boardgames/', include('boardgames.urls'))
]
```

**var\www\html\Python_PS\DjangoDemo\boardgames\boardgames\views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.


def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello!")
```

**\var\www\html\Python_PS\DjangoDemo\boardgames\boardgames\urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
]
```

After importing the include library in urls.py :

I got maximum depth exceeded error.

Or otherwise unable to display the Hello!.

I need to know the proper way of using the the url patters.

My Django version is 1.11 with Python 3.5.2

Comment: In your board games url's you include board games urls, this has nothing to do with folder structure, its simple recursion, I'm not sure what you're even trying to do with this url anyway though, and Nam Nguyễn's suggestion of reading the tutorial is probably a good idea

Comment: Please include `main.urls`

Comment: U mean should i add main.urls?

Comment: Have updated the code, working now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The urls.py file you had shown is your project URLs file. Create a separate urls.py in your app which i assume is boardgames. Inside that file add the following content:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from boargames import views

urlpatterns=[
   url(r'^board/$',views.home,name='home'),
 ]
```

So now in the browser you can invoke it as http://localhost:8000/views/board

Comment: I need to get the "Hello!" when i hit my  http://localhost:8000/  ie ) on default home page

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly importing it, your function name is "home" and you are trying to import views, which is not a best practice, The correct way to import is,

```
from boardgames.views import *
```

OR

```
from boardgames.views import home
```